# Android "screen redraw" developer device setting

Tags: android, android-view, android-version

On one of the Google IO 2013 Android sessions, they showed us there was a developer option that was changed on the phone, which shows you how many times the different views in your app get redrawn by colorindicators, which is useful to make your code as hardware-friendly as possible.

In the session they said in which version this was implemented. I'm using a 4.2.2 device, but as I can't seem to find this particular setting, I'm guessing it's implemented in 4.3.

I can't seem to find that particular video, as there are so many online. Hence I'm asking it here.

Comment: I'm running a stock S3 ROM at 4.1.2,  Settings->Developer Options->Drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

It tried "Show GPU overdraw", but it didn't do anything. It seems I had to close the settings menu for it to become active, which I didn't do previously.

I don't know in which version it was implemented, but it's there in 4.2.2